# number not entered correctly python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working with python on selenium
I'm trying to enter a time code (00:35:00:00) into a page from and excel file. in order to do so, I'm entering the digits 1 at the time. instead of getting the result 00:35:00:00 i keep getting 03:50:00:00.
The base function I' using is:

```
def extra_smart_clear_send_keys(self, tpl_locator, phrase):
    try:
        elem = WebDriverWait(driver=self._driver,
                             timeout=15,
                             poll_frequency=0.250) \
            .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(tpl_locator))
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b")
        for letter in phrase:
            elem.send_keys(letter)
            self.wait(1)
```

the value in the excel file is defined as text.
the function in the page is:

```
def edit_gross_dur(self, dur_gross):
    self.extra_smart_clear_send_keys(self.EDIT_GROSS_DURATION, dur_gross)
```

Comment: i doubt if this for loop is working? it just sends all the numbers at once.

Comment: it sends it one digit at the time